# Codeigniter Class Inheritance between modules (wiredesigns)

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, codeigniter-2

My CI2 app is using the wiredesigns modular layout.

I have a two modules called item and product in a a folder called modules like so:

```
/application
    /modules
        /item
        /product
```

In Item I have a controller called item which starts like this.

```
class Item extends MX_Controller
{
    //code here
}
```

What do I need to do to make my products controller extend my item controller in a different module

Comment: why do you want product controller to extend item controller. In an ideal behaviour modules are for different purposes.

Comment: they are for different purposes, items can be used for anything that needs sorting filtering categorizing and displaying. Products need to do all the same things they just have additional attributes such as prices and sku's (additional attributes are part of the item class anyway)

Comment: @raheelshan previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are trying to keep your code "DRY" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) which in CI means using a common controller like a My_Controller (see: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html).

Check out Phil Sturgeon's take: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY.

Comment: I think I understand. So I need to extend mx controller within application/core and then extend my item and product controllers from that?

Comment: Yes, MY_Controller will extend MX_Controller.  Then your Item controller will extend MY_Controller.

Comment: Thank you for your help, if you have time to take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002626/codeigniter-class-inheritance-between-modules-wiredesigns-again