# Codeigniter Class Inheritance between modules (wiredesigns) - again

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, codeigniter-2

I asked this question previously : [Codeigniter Class Inheritance between modules (wiredesigns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994457/codeigniter-class-inheritance-between-modules-wiredesigns/13995249#comment19322675_13995249)

I accepted an answer to that question which provided a way of doing what I want by extending a custom controller in application/core. This approach seemed sensible and offered the added benefit of allowing both modules to function independently.

However, Having thought about it, I am not sure this is the best approach for this situation because My Products controller will require almost all of the functionality of the item controller so this approach will leave my item controller almost empty - I'm not sure I like this.

**QUESTION 1**

Although I may still go with the approach previously suggested, I would like to know if there is a way to extend classes between modules so that I can weigh up the two options (see original question below)

**QUESTION 2**

Additionally, I think I should be able to re-use much of my model class, I can see that I would be able to do this using the MY_Model in app/core approach. But...

a) Is there a way to directly access another modules models?

b) Could I extend my models between modules in a similar way to question 1 for controllers

**PREVIOUS QUESTION**

My CI2 app is using the wiredesigns modular layout.

I have a two modules called item and product in a a folder called modules like so:

```
/application
    /modules
        /item
        /product
```

In Item I have a controller called item which starts like this.

```
class Item extends MX_Controller
{
    //code here
}
```

What do I need to do to make my products controller extend my item controller in a different module

Comment: so, you're saying that you would like to do something like `Class Item extends Item_base` where `Item_base` is another controller in another module, right?

Comment: I want Class Product extends Item where item and product are controllers in different modules. Item can be used on its own, product needs item. The point of having them in different modules is that they can both be used at the same time for different things

Comment: yes, you just changed the names... no need to confuse the issue further is there now. lol. p.s. how are you highlighting code in comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer here is:

> Don't

Why are you trying to do this? Place your logic into a library or some sort of shared file and implement a call to that library instead.

You could make `Item` an abstract class in your `application/libraries` folder and the autoloader built into HMVC will automatically load it. There is no reason this needs to be in a module, and it definitely doesn't need to be a controller.

Comment: I had kind of been told that what I asked how to do was a bad idea (and pointed to your blog article on DRY CI dev), I have gone down the route of extending MX_Controller and then extending this to my Item and Product controllers, suggested last time I asked this question. Are you saying this is a bad approach? Why?

Comment: If you are making base controllers they go in the application folder, because they are an application-wide dependency. If you put them in your modules then you have to either list includes each time, or force the autoloader to trawl through ever module until it happens to find it. If you're looking at my DRY article then follow its example - and don't put base controllers in modules.

Comment: Core is where you place Core classes that you are overloading, so it should go into application/libraries.